# Find duplicity files after using PhotoRec

Tags: ext4, duplicity

I've partly formatted a disc where my duplicity files was stored. I have used PhotoRec to recover the files but now they're all unsorted and without the correct filename. I have the files separated by extension. Is there a way to discover the duplicity files and recover my backup?

Comment: Are the backups encrypted or not, and how (symmetric or asymmetric)? What does a backup collection typically contain?

Comment: They're not encrypted. The collection contains photos, documents, some source code, etc

Comment: Sorry, actually they're encrypted. I have found all the gpg files, some are from duplicity and some (I think) are from gnupg. So now I have to figure out how recover my keys to try to decrypt the duplicity files.